# React Formik FieldArray error : A component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, forms, formik

I have a form built with Formik containing an array of objects. When I add a second element to the form with the add-button, I get the following error:

```
Warning: A component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled. This is likely caused by the value changing from a defined to undefined, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.
```

I have made sure that initial values is defined for the the form. I use the FieldArray component from formik. If I remove the time and rate fields, so it's only the name input in each object, I don't get the error, but when I add the time and rate fields, the error occurs. The component contains the following:

```
const TimeItemsForm = () => {
    const jiraItemsStore = useJiraItemsStore();

    function jiraTimeImported(timeItemIndex: number, importedHoursTotal: number, checkedItems: CheckedTimeItems) {
        // Add checked items to store
        jiraItemsStore.setJiraTable(timeItemIndex, checkedItems, importedHoursTotal);
    }

    const TimeItemSchema = Yup.object().shape({
        name: Yup.string().required('Required'),
        time: Yup.number().min(0).required('Required'),
        // rate: Yup.number().min(0).required('Required'),
    });

    const TimeItemsSchema = Yup.object().shape({
        timeItems: Yup.array().of(TimeItemSchema),
    })

    const initialValues = {
        timeItems: [
            {
                name: '',
                time: 0,
                rate: 0,
            },
        ],
    };

    return (
        <>
            <Formik
                validateOnChange={false}
                initialValues={initialValues}
                validationSchema={TimeItemsSchema}
                onSubmit={(values) => console.log(values)}>
                {({ values, errors, touched }) => (
                    <Form onChange={() => console.log("hs")}>
                        <FieldArray
                            name="timeItems"
                            render={arrayHelpers => (
                                <div>
                                    {values.timeItems && values.timeItems.length > 0 ? (
                                        values.timeItems.map((timeItem, index) => (
                                            <React.Fragment key={index}>
                                                    <Stack gap={2}>
                                                        <Flex alignItems="end" gap={4}>
                                                            <FormControl>
                                                            <FormLabel htmlFor="timeItems[${index}].name">Name</FormLabel>
                                                                    <Field as={Input} placeholder="Time Item Name" variant="filled" name={`timeItems[${index}].name`} />
                                                            </FormControl>

                                                            <FormControl>
                                                            <FormLabel htmlFor="timeItems[${index}].time">Time</FormLabel>
                                                            <InputGroup>
                                                                <Field as={Input} type="number" placeholder="0 Hours" variant="filled" name={`timeItems[${index}].time`} />
                                                                    <InputRightAddon children='Hours' />
                                                                </InputGroup>
                                                            </FormControl>

                                                            <FormControl>
                                                            <FormLabel htmlFor="timeItems[${index}].rate">Rate</FormLabel>
                                                                <InputGroup>
                                                                    <Field as={Input} type="number" placeholder="USD 0" variant="filled" name={`timeItems[${index}].rate`} />
                                                                        <InputRightAddon children='Hours' />
                                                                </InputGroup>
                                                            </FormControl>

                                                            <Flex flexShrink="0" gap={3} direction="column">
                                                                <Heading fontWeight="normal" size="sm">Apply Taxes & Discounts</Heading>
                                                                <Flex mb={0.5} gap={4}>
                                                                <Tooltip label='Tax 1' fontSize='sm'>
                                                                    <IconButton variant={true ? 'solid' : 'outline'} aria-label='Tax' icon={<TbReceipt />} />
                                                                </Tooltip>
                                                                    <IconButton variant='outline' aria-label='Discount' icon={<TbDiscount />} onClick={() => arrayHelpers.insert(index, { name: "", email: "" })} />
                                                                </Flex>
                                                            </Flex>
                                                        </Flex>
                                                        <Flex py={2} gap={10} justifyContent="space-between">
                                                            <TimeItemsTable timeItemIndex={index} jiraTimeImported={jiraTimeImported} />
                                                            <Flex gap={4}>
                                                                <IconButton aria-label='Create Time Item' icon={<MinusIcon />} onClick={() => arrayHelpers.remove(index)} />
                                                                <IconButton aria-label='Create Time Item' icon={<AddIcon />} onClick={() => arrayHelpers.insert(index, { name: "", email: "" })} />
                                                            </Flex>
                                                        </Flex>
                                                    </Stack>
                                                <Divider my={4} />
                                            </React.Fragment>
                                        ))
                                    ) : (
                                        <button type="button" onClick={() => arrayHelpers.push('')}>
                                            Add a Time Item
                                        </button>
                                    )}
                                    <Flex mt={6} gap={10} justifyContent="space-between">
                                        <Button colorScheme="purple" type="submit">Save</Button>
                                        {/* <TimeItemsStats /> */}
                                    </Flex>
                                </div>
                            )}
                        />
                    </Form>
                )}
            </Formik>
        </>
    )
}
```

**Solution:**
The arrayHelpers.push and arrayHelpers.insert didn't insert the values with the correct type, as seen in the code.

Comment: Is arrayHelpers.push('') is intended to add new item to timeItems array? If so, then you need to push exact same object structure as other timeItems because your fields expect values for name, time and rate to be defined

Comment: When this error occur? When you add new item or when you remove existing item?

Comment: @AndriusOlišauskas Oh yeah, this was it. Thanks for your attention on this obvious error on my part :)